# Differentiable functions and affine spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

Consider a function $F:A\to W$, with $A\subseteq V$. $F$ is said to be differentiable at $a\in A$ if there exists a $T\in \text{Hom}(V,W)$ such that
$$
\Delta F_a(\xi)=T(\xi)+o(\xi).
$$
$\Delta F_a(\xi)=F(a+\xi)- F(a)$.

> I want to understand what ($a+\xi$) means in this context.

It cannot be that this is a vector space $+$, as $A$ is not a vector space. The natural  question is this:
Is an open set, $A$, of a vector space, $V$, an *affine space* modeled on $V$?

In this case $a+\xi$ would be the affine map $\alpha : A\times V \to A$. My feeling, however,  is that the answer is *no* because $\xi$ need  be "sufficiently small" so that $a+\xi \in A$, and $\xi$ "sufficiently" small doesn't consitute a vector space.

Comment: But the intent of that displayed formula is that it hold only for $\|\xi\|$ sufficiently small. Why are you trying to make sense of all of this globally? And no, even if $A$ is open, generally it will not be an affine subspace.